# How to correct this query

Tags: php, mysqli

It always Gives error

I have tried putting variables in quotes felids names in quotes but still error

```
"UPDATE employee_info
        SET NAME=$Name, ADDRESS=$Address, EMAIL=$Email, CELL_NO=$Cell_no, CNIC=$Cnic, DESIGNATION=$Designation, BASIC_PAY=$Basic_pay, BONOUS=$Bonous, TOTAL_PAY=$Basic_pay+$Bonous
        WHERE ID=$ID"))
```

Updated ROW

Comment: why there are two brackets at last?

Comment: post your error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap text containing fields in quotes like-

```
"UPDATE employee_info SET NAME='$Name', ADDRESS='$Address', EMAIL='$Email', CELL_NO=$Cell_no, CNIC=$Cnic, DESIGNATION=$Designation, BASIC_PAY=$Basic_pay, BONOUS=$Bonous, TOTAL_PAY=$Basic_pay+$Bonous WHERE ID=$ID"
```

If there are more fields containing text then wrap them too.